# Integrate existing Grails app with Liferay better approach

Tags: grails, liferay, liferay-6

I have an existing grails app which I want to integrate with Liferay. I start playing with portlets but found that this will not work with existing controllers and seems Like I need to create a portlet for every controller.

Is there a better approach to integrate this app with out need to write a lot of portlets?

Comment: What exactly does not work? How do you call grails controller in your portlet?